# Issue with exporting to android from Godot 3.5.3

Tags: godot, godot3

after installing open jdk 11 & android studio (hedgehog) with

android sdk 14
build tools 34.0.0
ndk 21.4.707
*c make 3.10.2.49…
and custom android template in godot
every time i try to export my project to android i get:

Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

anyone had this issue? or has a lead?

thanks!